# How to save the error returned by a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I am trying to figure out how to get the error message returned from the proc sys.sp_testlinkedserver rather than the non-descriptive message returned by ERROR_MESSAGE().

The proc's message is:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XXXX_XXX_XXXXXXX" returned message "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied".

What ERROR_MESSAGE() returns is

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XXXX_XXX_XXXXXXX".

```
FETCH NEXT FROM LinkedServers INTO @ServerName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sys.sp_testlinkedserver @ServerName
        PRINT @ServerName + ': OK'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT @ServerName + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM LinkedServers INTO @ServerName
END
```

Comment: You may find some useful details here: [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server
Appendix 1: Linked Servers](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Appendix1.html)

Comment: @ErikDarling - thanks for the link. That doesn't cover quite what I am looking for.

Comment: As Erland states in the linked article, " the raw error messages from the provider are relayed as informational messages", so you can't capture it in TSQL.